# How to update many fields based on array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an e-learning app and I want the teacher to rate his students after finishing a lesson.

The problem is that I got in the response body coming from my app a list containing the reviews the teacher sent, and every student has a "reviews" field in his schema which contains all the reviews the student got.

I want to add for each student his own review from the array the teacher sent.

The first thing I would do is to use for loop but I think there is a more simple and basic solution.

I am using node js along with express and MongoDB with the mongoose orm.

The data coming from the teacher

```
const dataFromTeacher = [
  {
    stars: 4,
    studentId: '5335jfiehfdffd',
    teacherId: '9349jigj8hdhio',
  },
  {
    stars: 2,
    studentId: '9035jfiehfdffd',
    teacherId: '2249jigj8hdhio',
  },
];
```

Thank you,

Comment: Providing some sample data may make it easier for people to help. Otherwise it's a bit too unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: Sorry what can I show?

Comment: The data sent by teacher and sample schema.

Comment: Thanks for that first sample! I'm still not sure what exactly you're asking for. You could definitely loop over this array and migrate the data from it into some other data structures for students -- are you asking what kind of data structures to use for students? Or how to get it all into Mongo?

Comment: Sorry regarding not explaining that clearly, I want to know if there is a more simple or better solution than using for loop, thanks in advance

Comment: This is good way, it can manage all references and also rating, what you need more easy?

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time!